# Can't install Graphlab create on azure notebook

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, graphlab

So I'm testing https://notebooks.azure.com , and i wanted to install graphlab using pip, but i get the following error :

`Collecting https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/xxxxxx@gmail.com/4979-2629-7787-8767-049A-C0BB-5869-FBD6/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy., OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 403 Forbidden',))':/GraphLab-Create/2.1/xxxxxx@gmail.com/4979-2629-7787-8767-049A-C0BB-5869-FBD6/GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz`

I looked around and I found some answers that say you have to specify the proxy you're using, but I couldn't manage to find anything to do with a proxy in the azure paltform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions in here.

1) I can't install GraphLab on Python 3.5. 
I looked at the documenation and it seems GraphLab is only supported for Python 2 at this time. https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html

2) I can't install GraphLab on Azure Notebooks
The issue you are seeing with a proxy is due to Azure Notebooks not having the network open. Azure Notebooks restricts access to known sites. I have added graphlab.com as a known good site. You can now install graphlab in the way you originally tried.

`!pip install --upgrade --no-cache-dir https://get.graphlab.com/GraphLab-Create/2.1/EMAIL/TOKEN//GraphLab-Create-License.tar.gz`

Comment: Thank You @Christopher , now it's working like a charm

Comment: @Christopher, how can I add graphlab.com as a known site to Azure Notebooks?

Comment: The install works without a glitch but I get `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'` when I import graphlab.

Comment: Never mind. Restarting the kernel solved the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to install `graphlab-create` package on Azure notebook for Python 2.7 and 3.5, and failed on Python 3.5, but successed on Python 2.7. Please see below.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thaank you, installation worked perfectly on python 2.7 as you said, but now when I try to import graphlab I get the following error : `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'connect'
`